# Checkout to forward commit id

Tags: android, git, git-commit, git-checkout, repo

Lets suppose I synced repo 10 days back through `repo sync -c -m <manifest.xml>` command.

Now, I want to checkout to a forward commit id which is 5 ahead from where currently I am. (I also have 5 days back manifest file too), is that possible?

As git log cant help as I am on 10 days back repo so read 5 days back manifest and got forward commit id.

Answer (score 0):

`git log` has several useful options that allow you to analyze your commit tree. You can either use `git log master` (assuming you are on branch `master`), or `git log --all` (assuming you don't have too many branches) to get the commit id you are looking for.

You can also specify a date interval to filter the log output with `git log --after=<date> --until=<date>`.

Once you get the commit id you can checkout that commit as usual.